# Play Framework 2.x: How to make button submit for each news just once?

Tags: java, playframework

I'm Trying to code the button-submit for each news_id just once, i.e the user presses the button and the button does not see more

My Application.java

```
public static boolean flag = false;

public static Result exampleButton(Long id){
    News news = News.find.byId(id);
    if(!flag){
        //do something
        flag = true;
    }
    return ok();
}
```

My view.scala

```
@form(controllers.routes.Application.exampleButton(news.id)){
                        <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs active" id="thumbsUp" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span></button>
                    }
```

But it does not work properly. If the user pressed the button for one news, this button is not available for all the news. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Hm, just add new boolean field to your `News` model ie:

```
static boolean alreadyClicked;
```

So in view you can use simple condition check:

```
@if(!news.alreadyClicked){
     <button>Label</button>
}
```

Comment: Your question is ultra unclear, I gave you typical solution, but have no idea what you did wrong